# Django: iterate over all objects fills all the memory

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django (3.1.5) project with a postgresql database with the model I show below.

The problem is that I'm not able to iterate over all objects. When I try to iterate my memory gets full until the process needs to be killed.

How does `Article.objects.all()` iterate over objects? Does it first load all objects in memory?

I'm using a simple `for` to iterate:

```
for art in Article.objects.all():
    print(art)
    break
```

The model:

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def search(self, search_text):
        search_vector = \
            SearchVector(
                'title', weight='A',config='portuguese'
                ) + \
            SearchVector(
                'author_name', weight='A',config='portuguese'
                ) + \
            SearchVector(
                'description', weight='B',config='portuguese'
                ) + \
            SearchVector(
                'body', weight='C',config='portuguese'
                )

        search_query = SearchQuery(
            search_text, config='portuguese'
        )
        search_rank = SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
        qs = (
            self.get_queryset()
            .filter(search_vector=search_query)
            .annotate(rank=search_rank)
            .order_by('-rank')
        )
        return qs

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    description = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.URLField(unique = True,max_length = 500)
    url_basename = models.URLField(max_length = 500,blank=True,null = True)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('accounts.Author',related_name = 'autores')
    author_name = models.TextField(blank=True,null = True)
    jornal = models.ForeignKey(Jornal,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = 'jornal')
    mongo_id = models.CharField(max_length = 30,unique = True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    exclusive = models.BooleanField(blank=True,null = True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    entidades = models.TextField()

    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish_date', )
        indexes = (GinIndex(fields=["search_vector"]),)


    objects = ArticleManager()
```

Comment: **Yes** `Article.objects.all()` will load all the objects to memory, (will make a database query to select all of the rows). Perhaps this might help a little [Django docs - iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#iterator)

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's bad. I realized this problem because I just populated my DB after a testing phase, where I only had a few hundred objects. Any advice on how can I iterate over all objects without loading them all in memory?

Comment: Ok, sorry. Didn't open the link before writing. Yes, it helped. Thanks.